# Replacing if statement with for loop (Java)

Tags: java, string, methods

I was working on a project and one of the comments that I received was that my if statement was too long. I agree with this but I'm still confused how to replace it with a for loop that was suggested. It has been driving me crazy. The project was to analyse the consonants in a sentence and report back if they are in it. Here is my code that I used. The project has been since marked so this is more of a "where is my mistake/ where can this be improved question".

```java
if ((userInput.contains("b"))||(userInput.contains("c"))||(userInput.contains("d"))||
    (userInput.contains("f"))||(userInput.contains("g"))||(userInput.contains("h"))||
    (userInput.contains("j"))||(userInput.contains("k"))||(userInput.contains("l"))||
    (userInput.contains("m"))||(userInput.contains("n"))||(userInput.contains("p"))||
    (userInput.contains("q"))||(userInput.contains("r"))||(userInput.contains("s"))||
    (userInput.contains("t"))||(userInput.contains("v"))||(userInput.contains("w"))||
    (userInput.contains("x"))||(userInput.contains("y"))||(userInput.contains("z")))
        //checking for consonants
        results += "The input contains consonants";
else 
    results += "The input contains no consonants";
```

Comment: You should probably post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Use and regular expression.

Comment: You could also check if it's not a vowel

Comment: @Leo that would give false positive for strings containing only vowels and characters which are neither vowels nor consonants (like spaces, and special chars)

Comment: @Gorkk [A-Za-z] minus vowels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, time to learn Regular Expression or RegEx.  So that the you if statement would be:

```
if (userInput.matches(".*[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz].*"))
   results += "The input contains consonants";
else 
   results += "The input contains no consonants";
```

For more read the this tutorial [Java Regex - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: Did you try this? `matches` requires the _entire_ string to match the regex, i.e. this would match only strings of a single consonant.

Comment: @xlm and tobia_k you guys are right, I forgot the .* before and after.  Updated.

Answer (score 5):

You could create an array of consonants (maybe as a static constant of your class), and use a function doing the work, something along the lines of (pseudo code here)

```
boolean hasConsonants(String userInput) {
    for (String consonant : consonants)
        if (userInput.contains(consonant)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Then you would simple call

```
if (hasConsonants(userInput))
    results += "The input contains consonants";
else
    results += "The input contains no consonants";
```

P.S. probably better to have your `consonants` array to be a `char[]` and use `char` instead of `String` in the *for each* loop

Comment: `boolean hasConsonants(String userInput)` :)

Comment: indeed, fixing that (had really started with pseudo-code then made it a bit more correct java along the way, missing some things ;))

Answer (score 2):

To use a `for` loop, you could do something like the following:

```
for (char c = 'b'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    if (c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
        continue;
    if (userInput.contains(String.valueOf(c))) {
        return "The input contains consonants";
    }
}
return "The input contains no consonants";
```

Comment: Favorite answer because it doesn't require manually building the consonants alphabet (only vowels), and it also uses beginner friendly constructs (and the OP *specifically* asked how to do it with a `for` loop).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it like this:

```
private String[] mCharacters = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };

public boolean hasSelectedCharacters(String str) {
    for (final String c : mCharacters) {
        if (str.contains(c)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If the input string contains any of the listed strings, it returns true, otherwise false. Identical to your long if, but more readable.

Comment: I would prefer if the selected characters were passed in as an additional parameter to `hasSelectedcharacters`, instead of being in a field.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean containsConsonant = 
    Pattern.compile("[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]").matcher(userInput).find();
```

Comment: Using a pattern here is indeed much more elegant (if that works with the 'using a for loop' part of the op ofc). Maybe using a case insensitive match though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like:

```
if(java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(?i)[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]").matcher(line).find())
    System.out.println("Contains consonants");
```

Comment: Yes, this is definitely best, but I was under the impression the OP wanted a `for` loop.

Comment: +1, for OP asked how to improve his condition, and using a loop was just one suggestion (and probably not the best one).

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] consonants = "bcdfghkjlmnpqrstvwxyz".toCharArray();
results = "The input contains no consonants";

for (int i = 0; i < consonants.length; i++)
    if (userinput.contains(String.valueOf(consonants[i])))
        results = "The input contains consonants";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd write this as a loop (I'm assuming that your string is already lowercased):

```
public static boolean containsConsonants(String s) {
    for (char c : "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".toCharArray())
        if (s.indexOf(c) >= 0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Here's another way, using a regular expression:

```
private static final Pattern consonantPattern =
    Pattern.compile("[a-z&&[^aeiou]]");
public static boolean containsConsonants(String s) {
    return consonantPattern.matcher(s).find();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use regex expressions, eg:

```
if (userInput.matches (".*[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwx]+.*"))
    results += "has consonants";
else
    results += "no consonants";
```

If you can ensure that no symbols will be used, then a simpler version would be:

```
if (!userInput.matches (".*[aeiou]+.*"))
    results += "has consonants";
else
    results += "no consonants";
```

Tweak to suit for case sensitivity.

Comment: The first part is good, by why would `userInput.matches (".*[aeiou]+.*")` mean 'no consonants'? The `.*`s could be full of them.

Comment: Sorry, but it's still wrong. If the check is true, the string could also be empty, and if the check fails the string could have both consonants and vocals. Also, that triple negation makes my head spin. IMHO, better just stick with the first version. It may have a few more characters, but is much much easier.

Answer (score -1):

**It will be more efficient and readable**

```
if(Pattern.matches("[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]+",userInput)){  
    ----code----
}
else{
    ----other code----  
}
```